# How to include Python namespace package in AWS Lambda distribution zip?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a Python namespace package that I want to install into an AWS lambda. The package directory structure looks like this:

```
mypackage
    foo
       __init__.py
       bar.py
```

Note that there is no `__init__.py` at the top level because it is a namespace package.

I want to include it in my lambda directly without installing it into a layer, if possible. My distribution zip contents looks like this:

```
mypackage
    foo
       __init__.py
       bar.py
my_app
    __init__.py
    handler.py
```

In the above, `handler.py` imports `mypackage.foo.bar.ExampleClass`.

I'm getting "Unable to import ..." errors because "No module named mypackage". That `mypackage` package I am importing needs to be a namespace package so I can't just put a `__init__.py` file in it.

Is there a way of using Python namespace packages in AWS Lambda?

Comment: Hi John, are you using SAM, CDK, Terraform or are you manually uploading the lambda function to AWS?

Comment: Manually zipping and uploading, using another method is not an option for me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will have `my_app` and `mypackage` directories on the same level and AWS lambda could find your `handler.py`. This also assumes that there won't be any `__init__.py` file inside the `mypackage` directory.

```py
import sys
import os

if 'LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT' in os.environ:
  sys.path.append(f"{os.environ['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT']}/mypackage/foo")

import foo.bar.ExampleClass
```

Now, if you add `__init__.py` inside the `mypackage` directory, you will be able to import it using the following syntax:

```py
import sys
import os

if 'LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT' in os.environ:
  sys.path.append(f"{os.environ['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT']}/mypackage")

import mypackage.foo.bar.ExampleClass
```